# Problem solving an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to show that the solution for $y'=\frac{-x^3y^2}{x^4+y^4}$ that satisfies $y(0)=1$ is an even function.

Here's my approach
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-x^3y^2}{x^4+y^4} >>>>>>>> \frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^3y^2}$$
Simplifying it yields: 
$$x'+\frac{x}{y^2}=-\frac{y^2}{x^3}$$ So we have Bernoulli's equation, plugging in $z=x^4$  yields $$z'+\frac{4x^4}{y^2}=-y^2$$ with an integrating factor of $$\large {e^\frac{-4}{y}}$$

And finally we get $$e^\frac{-4}{y}z=\int-e^\frac{-4}{y}y^2dy$$ which is an integral that cannot be solved with elementary functions, is there something that I am missing in here?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to solve the differential equation.  Note that if $y(x)$ is a solution of the differential equation, so is $y(-x)$, and it satisfies the same initial condition.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? not sure I get your point

Comment: @RobertIsrael You make a good point, but the argument only holds if you  prove uniqueness.

Comment: @PierreCarre we can prove uniqueness, can we not? The function above is indeed continuous in the (0,1) environment, and I haven't tried it yet but I assume so is the derivative with respect to y

Comment: The Existence and Uniqueness theorem applies everywhere except the origin.  So the solution of the initial value problem is unique on the interval where it exists.  A separate argument shows that the solution stays bounded, so it exists on $(-\infty, \infty)$.